# Can I make the compiler ignore bound mismatch error? (Or fix this instance of it)

Tags: java, generics

I have a method (that I can't change, it belongs to a different project) defined in an interface that limits the input classes using generics to a Class that extends a Class (which in turn implements an interface), like this:

```
<P extends ParentInterface, E extends P> void register(Class<E> cl, Class<P> parent);
```

This works fine when you're calling it normally, but in order to make it easier to register a potentially large number of classes this way (and unregister the same set when needed) I was hoping to store them in a `Map<Class<? extends ParentInterface>, Class<? extends ParentInterface>>` (or similar) and loop over it when registering/unregistering. Unfortunately this - predictably - leads to compile time errors saying bound mismatch:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method register(Class<E>, Class<P>) is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#5-of ? extends ParentInterface, Class<capture#13-of ? extends ParentInterface>). The inferred type capture#5-of ? extends ParentInterface is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends P>
```

Can I get around this in some way, or am I stuck doing individual calls and making sure I'm keeping the register and unregister calls synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does it help to make the class generic, that will **EDIT** not encapsulate but extends the Map interface?

```
public class TestMap <P extends ParentInterface, E extends P> extends HashMap implements Map {
    void registerall(){
        Class<E> key = (Class<E>) this.keySet().iterator().next();
        Class<P> val = (Class<P>) this.get(key);
        register(key, val);
    }

}
```

Comment: It won't work. The map can hold one entry at most (without polluting the heap anyways).

Comment: Sorry Ben, I don't understand what you're talking about. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Say you have a `Test<Foo, Bar>`. You will be able to insert the key-value pair `(Bar.class, Foo.class)` into `map`. Any other pair will be rejected.

Comment: well yes, I have tried it with one element a but I did not think it over.

Answer (score 1):

When (un)registering simply make use of wildcard capture and `asSubclass(Class)`:

```
Class<? extends ParentInterface> parent = entry.getValue();
Class<? extends ParentInterface> child = entry.getKey();
registerWithCapturedParent(parent, child);

private <P extends ParentInterface> void registerWithCapturedParent(Class<P> parent,
    Class<? extends ParentInterface> child) {
    Class<? extends P> boundedChild = child.asSubclass(parent);
    registry.register(boundedChild, parent);
}
```